# Cannot capture screenshot on Android emulator on Mac

Tags: android, macos, android-emulator

When trying to capture a screenshot on the emulator (API level 23 and 24) of Android Studio v2.2.2 I get this error:

> The screenshot could not be captured. Check settings to verify that
>   your chosen adb path is valid.

So I clicked "Extended settings " > "Settings" tab and the "**Use detected ADB location**" toggle is turned on.

What am I missing here?

Edit:

After switching the "**Use detected ADB location**" toggle OFF and manually sething the path to that API level adb it started working. So the question now is why the "Use detected ADB location" setting in the Android Studio emulators is not working on OSX?

Comment: where is extended settings. I can't find it.

Comment: It should be the lowers button (the "...") https://koenig-media.raywenderlich.com/uploads/2016/01/18_android_emulator_2_0_extended_controls.png

Comment: I've manually set the correct path and it's still can't take screenshots

Comment: What do you mean by "that API level adb"? Isn't there only one adb in the /Users/username/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/ folder?
I tried setting that manually but still get the same error.

Comment: @VladimirAmiorkov please explain 'that API level adb'. doesn't seem to apply to the `adb`

Comment: @AXE try `adb kill-server` followed by `adb start-server`. Restarting the `adb` fixed it for me

Comment: @Abhijit, unfortunately it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, it was the setting "USB debugging" OFF.

Settings app > "Developer options" > enable "USB debugging"

If you don't see "Developer options", you can enable it by tapping the "Build Number" field several times in the section "About emulator device".